# Test Cases in Python Using Doctest

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I write a program to divide 2 numbers along with exception handling and test cases in Python 3.6 ? I read that it can be done by importing 'doctest'.

Comment: Please share your code in question.

Comment: Three things required in question 1) Code to divide two numbers 2) Exception handling in Python 3) Writing Unit test cases for the above code

Comment: Unit test cases can be written using unittest, pytest, doctest modules.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuVBF.jpg

Comment: The above link is my code snapshot. Is it fine  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Doctest` is a module included in the Python programming language's standard library that allows the easy generation of tests based on the output from the standard Python interpreter shell, cut and pasted into doc-strings.

You can write your code as:

**divide.py**

```
def divide(a, b):
    """
    >>> divide(8, 4)
    2
    >>> divide(-12, 3)
    -4
    >>> divide(4, 0)
    "Denominator can't be zero"
    """
    try:
        result = a//b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        result = "Denominator can't be zero"

    return result
```

*Each '>>>' line is run as if in a python shell, and counts as a test.
The next line, if not '>>>' is the expected output of the previous line.
If anything doesn't match exactly (including trailing spaces), the test fails.*

**Running the doctest**

You run doctest like this(write the commands in the terminal):

`$ python3 -m doctest -v doctest_trial.py` , or simply

`$ python3 -m doctest doctest_trial.py`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuVBF.jpg    This is my code. I hope this is proper implementation because it is running fine. The only issue is that I have written the test case outside the function.

Comment: Well yes, the `tests` should be written within the function.
Also, the answer is yet another way to use `doctest`. I generally prefer this way. Rather than importing in the code, we can use it in the shell while running the script.